# In a dataset with multiple peaks, how do I find FWHM of each peak (Python)?

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing, data-processing

Here's my denoised data:[image]

I've calculated my peaks, but if I define the peak width as full width at half maximum (FWHM) (while assuming zero is defined as the smallest point in data between ~25 to ~375 on x axis), is there a Numpy/Scipy way to calculate their width? I'm okay with coding my own function, but I'm not sure how to begin an implementation since there are multiple peaks in my data.

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this problem?